# Possible to use LVM partitions inside a vmbuilder created KVM virtual machine?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, partition, lvm, kvm-virtualization

I have an Ubuntu 9.10 host system with LVM partitions running KVM. I've been creating VMs using vmbuilder using LVM partitions for each VM instead of files for the VMs.

When I configure a VM using vmbuilder --part, the partitions in the file I'm using are created as regular partitions (sda1, sda2, etc.).

What I'd like to do is use LVM inside of the VM in case I need to resize the partitions at some point.  But I don't see any options for doing that using the vmbuilder tool. It seems like this might be a common request to avoid using kpartx, etc.

Is there something I'm missing, or is this just not possible with vmbuilder?

Comment: Do you mean you want vmbuilder create an logical volume, or do you want vmbuilder to use a logical volume you have created?

Answer (score 2):

If the partition is in qcow format you can use like

```
qemu-img resize partition.qcow2 +5GB
```

and then

```
kpartx
```

in the guest.

Answer (score 1):

VMBuilder does not support that (and I don't think it's actually possible, without running the VM).

I'd use virt-install to define the VM and then run standard Ubuntu installer (possibly with preseed data).